# Modify/Edit PhAsset Image by Cropping

Tags: swift, xcode, phasset, photosframework

is there any way to modify/edit phasset image by cropping or edited one?
I have array of asset, I wanna crop image of asset by getting image from selected asset and passing it cropping controller and in return want to change that cropped image in selected asset.

There is my code to understand well

```
func presentCropViewController(with:IndexPath) {
    self.allPhotos[with.item].getImage { (img) in
        if let image = img{
              self.indexPathForCropping = with
            let cropViewController = CropViewController(image: image)
            cropViewController.delegate = self
            cropViewController.view.tintColor = UIColor.themeGreen()
            self.present(cropViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }


}
```

after passing image from asset I got cropped image with this method

```
 func cropViewController(_ cropViewController: CropViewController, didCropToImage image: UIImage, withRect cropRect: CGRect, angle: Int) {
    cropViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    // Here i get the cropped image and want to update selected asset with this image

}
```

I'll appreciate if you mentioned down vote reason too so I prepare my question accordinglly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution may its not an efficient way to do but solved my problem

```
extension PHAsset {

func updateChanges(with img:UIImage,completion:@escaping(PHAsset?)->()){

    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        // create cropped image into phphotolibrary
        PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: img)
    }) { (success, error) in
        if success{
            // fetch request to get last created asset
            let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
            fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"creationDate", ascending: false)]
            fetchOptions.fetchLimit = 1
            let fetchResult: PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.image, options: fetchOptions)

            if let asset = fetchResult.firstObject{
                // replace your selected asset with new cropped one
                completion(asset)
            }else{
                completion(nil)
            }

        }else{
            completion(nil)
        }
    }

}
```

}

simply pass cropped/modified image and get new asset with same cropped/modified image